No puedo hacer funcionar el useNavigate()
Estoy trabajando en este proyecto para mi portfolio, la idea es que si el usuario ya esta registrado en mi base de datos la aplicación renderice un texto mostrando el error y después redirija el navegador a la pagina de login, sin embargo no puedo hacer que esto funcione, creo que al devolver el error se para la ejecución del bloque try, pero no se me ocurre como solucionarlo.
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'

const Register = () => {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
  });

  const [err, setError] = useState(null);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInputs(prev=>({...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}))
  }

  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()  
    try{
      await axios.post('http://localhost:8800/api/auth/register', inputs);
      navigate('/login')
    } catch(err){
      setError(err.response.data)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form>
        <input required type="text" name='username' placeholder='Username' onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input required type="email" name='email' placeholder='Email' onChange={handleChange}/>
        <input required type="password" name='password' placeholder='Password' onChange={handleChange}/>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Sign up</button>
        {err && <p>{err}</p>}
        <span>Already have an account? <br/><Link to='/login'>login!</Link></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register


Si capturas el error con catch no deberia detenerse el programa, probaste si el endpoint funciona con alguna herramienta como Postman? Si es asi y te funciona bien, podrias agregar mas detalles de como tenes configurado Router-dom, asi como la version que estas utilizando

estoy usando le version 6.23, el back lo tengo así en el fragmento de auth:
`db.query(q, [req.body.email, req.body.username], (err, data) => {
if (err) return res.json(err)
if(data.length) return res.status(409).json('user already exists!')
    // hash the password and create a user
    
    })`


Pero modifica la pregunta mejor, los comentarios no son para el código. Tambien agrega cualquier tipo de mensaje de la consola que te aparezca. El problema de estas preguntas que usan librerias es que los que preguntan muestran solo un componente y se supone que los demas deben 'adivinar' lo que esta mal.
